# jQueryMobile-enabled site within a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

OK, here's what I'm trying to achieve :

- I have a very basic .html page, based on jQuery Mobile
- I have another, "normal" website with a - let's say - rectangular `div` in it
- I want to make my jQuery Mobile website appear in that `div`

**Notes :**

- `<iframe>`s are out of the question, unless you know how I could make it work with the parent website being able to access the "child", same-domain, from localhost.
- when simply trying to copy-paste the "core" of the jQuery Mobile inside my `div` (not the outter tags, just the main page + the necessary scripts) the page does show up, though quite a mess actually.

Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE** : Here's the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/X5xys/

---

And the code...

**HTML :**

```
<div id="preview"> 
    <div id="iframe">
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Header</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <a data-role="button" id="mybutt" href="#">
                    Click me
                </a>
                <a data-role="button" id="mybutt" href="#">
                    Click me
                </a>
                <a data-role="button" id="mybutt" href="#">
                    Click me
                </a>
                <a data-role="button" id="mybutt" href="#">
                    Click me
                </a>
                <a data-role="button" id="mybutt" href="#">
                    Click me
                </a>
                <a data-role="button" id="mybutt" href="#">
                    Click me
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>          
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
        #preview {
            margin:50px auto;
            background-size: 376px 678px;
            width: 376px; max-width: 376px;
            height: 678px; max-height: 678px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #preview #iframe {
            margin:92px auto;
            border:1px solid black;
            width:320px; max-width: 320px;
            height:480px; max-height: 480px;

        }
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: @KawineshSK Here you are - please have a look at the update! ;-)

Comment: @popnoodles Code has just been added!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a `Id="page"` for you `data-role="page"` and give the following css

```
#page{
    position:relative;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X5xys/2/)

Comment: Well, yes... simple as it may seem, **that** was it! Thanks A LOT, buddy! ;-)